# Unexpected end-of-file with header file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem in VS2015:

I have a header file:

```
#ifndef DATATYPES_H
#define DATATYPES_H
    const char *OPCODES[16];
    typedef struct symbol{
        struct symbol *next;
        char label[20];
        int address;
        int external;
        int operation;
    }symbolTable;

    typedef struct ops{
        unsigned int ARE: 2;
        unsigned int destAddrs: 2;
        unsigned int orgnAddrs: 2;
        unsigned int opcode: 4;
        unsigned int group: 2;
        unsigned int rnd: 2;
        unsigned int non: 1;
    }opword;
    extern int dc;
    extern int ic;

    extern symbolTable *head;
    extern symbolTable *tail;
#endif
```

When I build the solution (it's a basic command-line application i C), I get this weird problem 'unexpected end-of-file found' in the file above ('datatypes.h'). I can't seem to understand why this is happening. 
Just FYI, I set VS2105 to be as close as possible to ANSI C, i.e, no extensions, compile as C etc.

Thanks,
Elad

Comment: The code you've provided is fine. You'll also want to show some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the problem is in something in the back of the C file, probably has to do with encoding or something, since my files were brought into VS from another text editor.

I rewrote the `#include guards` and it worked just fine. Luckily, those header were quite short, rewriting a long header would be a pain in the *** and a huge waste of time.